# MonoDevelop ASP.NET - where are the object properties/events listed?

Tags: c#, asp.net, monodevelop

I must be missing something really obvious here, but I can't seem to figure out where the object properties/events window for elements on my ASP.NET page is.  I have a Properties window, but it is scoped at the Application level and only gives me things like Build and Deployment actions.

Can anybody get me pointed in the right direction?

Thank you!

ps - I have googled the heck out of this, but can't find anything. Thanks, again!

Comment: I believe monodevelop does not have asp.net editor right now. If you look on their website, you can see what the suite offers.

Comment: @MilkyWayJoe: Hmm...unless I'm mistaken, I'm pretty sure MonoDevelop supports ASP.NET.  Its available as an option when you're starting a new project, and it even includes a bundled server.

Comment: It does support asp.net projects, but it doesn't seem to have an editor.

Comment: Ah. I see what you mean. Thanks for the input!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@MilkyWayJoe is correct.  The Mono Editor does not support ASP.NET at this time.